# how to implement non recursive inOrder traversal

Tags: java, c++

i want to do inorder traversal not using recursive and to put the nodes  in an array given the size of the BSTmap, it is easy to use recursive put i need to put the nodes in an array !!

Comment: @Nada - use some extra pointers but that is not the standard practice.

Comment: i did it recursively but i'm stuck in putting them in an array, im thinking of using queue ?

Comment: @Nada Consider using something like `std::vector` combined with `std::back_inserter_iterator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be an array? If not, you could use a linked list to add and remove the nodes without needing to know the size of the BSTmap.